# Check if an object (or just a class) has a property

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a class:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
       x:number;
       y:number;
    }
}
```

Then I have a string, "x". How can I check if MyClass has property "x"?

If I create an instance of MyClass and then do:

```
myClassInstance.hasOwnProperty("x");
```

it returns false unless x has a default value set. But I don't want to set default values for each property. It would be best if I even could do this without creating instance of MyClass.

Comment: I want to do this in TypeScript level, not JavaScript.

Comment: TypeScript does not exist at runtime. TypeScript is translated into JavaScript before it is executed.

Comment: If you explain, why you want to check for some property at runtime, maybe there is some other way to achieve what you attempt.

Comment: I have a base Style class, which has a list of all available SVG attributes. Then I have classes which extend Style class and contain some additional information, like lineLength - these are not SVG attributes, but I want to keep them in style as I want to keep all values responsible for visual part of an element in one place. So when I create SVG element I need to set all attributes of base Style class on it, but not set those like lineLength. So I thought I could create an instance of Style and check if an attribute is in this class.

Comment: I imagine I could use getters and setters instead and then do this:
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(style), "x")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript before execution. In the final JavaScript code, the type information from TypeScript is not available anymore. So there is no possibility to check TypeScript type information at runtime.

---

If you want to do a check at compile-time, you can use interfaces as in the following example:

```
interface IHasX
{
    x:any;
}

class MyClassA {
    x:number;
    y:number;
}

class MyClassB {
    y:number;
}

function Test(param: IHasX)
{
    // Do something with param.x 
}

var objA = new MyClassA();
var objB = new MyClassB();

Test(objA);
Test(objB);
```

The last line `Test(objB);` will fail to compile because the TypeScript compiler knows that `objB` is of type `MyClassB` and that that class has no property named `x` as required by the interface `IHasX`.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do this. I released an enhanced version of the TypeScript compiler that allows you to list all members of a class or an interface. For example you can do the following:

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
}

function printMembers(clazz: Class) {
    let fields = clazz.members.filter(m => m.type.kind !== 'function'); //exclude methods.
    for(let field of fields) {
        let typeName = field.type.kind;
        if(typeName === 'class' || typeName === 'interface') {
            typeName = (<Class | Interface>field.type).name;
        }
        console.log(`Field ${field.name} of ${clazz.name} has type: ${typeName}`);
    }
}

//then, somewhere in your code:
let p = new Person();
printMembers(p.constructor.getClass());
```

and this is the output:

```
$ node main.js
Field name of Person has type: string
Field surname of Person has type: string
Field age of Person has type: number
Field country of Person has type: string
```

You can find all the details you need [here](https://github.com/pcan/reflec-ts)